# How to start XBMC instead of Unity

Tags: unity, gui, xbmc

How can I set Ubuntu to start XBMC at login instead of Unity?

I know I can choose between the two interfaces when logging out, but it always goes on to Unity when booting.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

What I have understand from your post is you want to set XMBS as Default login session.

open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type as

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s XBMC -a <user_name of your>
```